# java.sql.sqlException:no such column: employID

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc

Here is my code I am getting the following error"`java.sql.sqlException`:no such column: employID" and I have rechecked my db table column name is correct `employID` nothing wrong with that but still getting the same error please help I am trying to load the table data based on the first column into a textboxes using netbeans IDE and sqlite database.

```
private void tableEmployeeMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                           
    try{ 
    int row=tableEmployee.getSelectedRow();
     String tableClick=(tableEmployee.getModel().getValueAt(row, 0).toString());
     String sql="SELECT * FROM employeeInfo WHERE employID=' "+tableClick+" ' ";

     pst=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
     rs=pst.executeQuery();
     if(rs.next()){
         String add1=rs.getString("employID");
         empid.setText(add1);
         String bdd=rs.getString("name");
         name.setText(bdd);
         String cdd=rs.getString("surname");
         surname.setText(cdd);
         String ddd=rs.getString("age");
         age.setText(ddd);     
     }         
     }
    catch(Exception e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e);
    }
```

n.b. the `employID` column in my database is set 
to `INTEGER` can that or my query inside my code have any connection with the error type..
Thanks.

EDIT: The DDL sentence

```
CREATE TABLE "employeeInfo" (
"employID " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL , 
"name" CHAR, "surname" CHAR, 
"age" INTEGER, "username" VARCHAR, "password" VARCHAR)
```

Comment: First thing to fix: don't build your SQL like that. Use parameterized SQL instead. But I strongly suspect that you really haven't got a column called exactly that... is it possible that it differs in case? (I wouldn't *expect* it to be case sensitive, but stranger things have happened.)

Comment: can you paste the structure of the database? (`SHOW CREATE TABLE employeeInfo`)

Comment: CREATE TABLE "employeeInfo" ("employID             " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY  NOT NULL , "name" CHAR, "surname" CHAR, "age" INTEGER, "username" VARCHAR, "password" VARCHAR)

Comment: @JonSkeet please can you give me an example of how to parameterize it and please check with my database structure as shown above

Comment: @CarlosRobles I have rechecked that no thing is wrong with that you can see my database structure is as shown above

Comment: Start up `sqlite3` in a command window and do `.schema employeeInfo`.

Comment: Look at any guide to PreparedStatement and it'll show you how to use parameters... and you should double check that the table you've actually got was created with that SQL.

Comment: Thanks guys, I have solved the problem after using .trim() function for the column name as follows                                    String add1=rs.getString("employID".trim());

Comment: So the problem was that the name DID differ. In this case, there's a blank space after the name.

Comment: yeah that's it what I traced and have deleted the old table and created it again!

Answer (score 0):

From the error it is clear that the resultset does not have the column named 'employID'. To troubleshoot this issue you can do either of these:
1. Inspect the resultset metadata and look at the column names that you are getting. 
2. Or use column position in resultset.getString() methods to get the values and verify if you are getting employID values.

Comment: thanks yeah I traced that and found the column name "employID" was something like this  "employID   " the space bars have to clear them by simply recreating the table...